# Toggle through Reactjs Mapped Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to figure out how to only show one item in my array at a time and then click back and fourth through them using to buttons. Currently right now if there are 4 items in the array all 4 are shown on the page. But I'd like to show them one at a time and then be back to click back and fourth through them. I've built this using hooks.

Here is my current code:

```
<div>
 {[...Array(stepBlock)].map((e, i) => 
   <div className={'stepBlock'} key={i}>
        <div>{details[i].name}</div>
   </div>
 )}
 </div>
 <div>
    <div>previous</div>
    <div>next</div> 
  </div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an `index` state variable to track the active index state. Since you want to render all the array items but hide the inactive ones, you can conditionally add a `hidden` CSS class based on the active index. The 'Previous' and 'Next' buttons can update the state by calling `setIndex` (the state updater function). You should pass a function to `setIndex` since the new state depends on the previous state. And you can disable the buttons if the index is out of bounds.

```js
const [index, setIndex] = useState(0)
const names = ['John', 'Paul', 'George', 'Ringo']
```

```
<>
  {names.map((name, i) => (
    <div key={i} className={`name ${i !== index ? 'hidden' : ''}`}>
      {name}
    </div>
  ))}
  <div>
    <button
      disabled={index === 0}
      onClick={() => setIndex((prevIndex) => prevIndex - 1)}
      className="button"
    >
      Previous
    </button>{' '}
    <button
      disabled={index === names.length - 1}
      onClick={() => setIndex((prevIndex) => prevIndex + 1)}
      className="button next-button"
    >
      Next
    </button>
  </div>
</>
```

[image: Edit romantic-jackson-q7fkh]

Comment: the details part was just to display this is where the info would go.. I'm trying to actually toggle the div named stepBlock has that is where I have the key "i" already assigned too. While your example does work it confuses me due to that.

Comment: @Robert Can you add the code involving `stepBlock` to the question?

Comment: It is already there from my original post. I'm mapping the array to it. and it creates right now 4 blocks. StepBlock is simply === 4. i named the div class StepBlock and so the result is 4 white blocks on the page. Instead of showing all 4. I'm simply trying to show one at a time then toggle through on my next and previous button..

Comment: @Robert Why do you need to map over the whole array if you only want to display one item at a time? You only need to keep track of the active index in the array. Let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: Because I'm going to be modifying elements within each part of the array via a drag and drop.

Comment: Well, you mentioned in the question you don't want to show all the 4 array items. I don't understand why you need to `map` and render something for each element I'm afraid.

Comment: I just want to display one at a time yet still have them there.

Comment: So, you only want to display the active item and hide the rest using CSS?

Comment: yes pretty much because I am trying to create a area to modify a lot of data. Just need to know how to toggle through each "key={i}" so that way I can make the adjusts then hit a save button to update the database.

Comment: @Robert Just updated my answer and the CodeSandbox to render all the array items in the DOM but hide the inactive ones using CSS.

Comment: That works thanks! However only issue is since I'm using div's and not buttons the disabled code does not appear to work so I always end up going to empty div's bc it doens't stop moving forward. 
 <div 
                        disabled={index === stepBlock.length - 1}
                        onClick={() => setIndex((prevIndex) => prevIndex + 1)}
                        className={'nextBTN'}>next</div>
                     </div>

Comment: @Robert Why not use buttons? The [`disabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled) attribute is not supported in `div`s.